# Sync updated project to old project in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, synchronization, tfs-2015, checkin

My desktop at work need to be replace, so while waiting to be replaced, I keep working on my laptop, now I have done a lot of updates to the project I was working on, but when I try to merge this new version with the old one in the TFS it only allows me to save it as a new project because the new computer and the updated project.

Can someone please show me how to do it (or direct me to the question if already posted), or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get latest for the project on you desktop or laptop, copy the updated files to the local files from TFS, resolve merge issues and checkin.

Comment: Thanks, it was really easy.